# Vertical Padding for tailwind container class

Tags: tailwind-css

I was looking at tailwind doc for container class and saw how it could be customized in `tailwind.config.js`, [likely so](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/container#adding-horizontal-padding):

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    container: {
      padding: {
        DEFAULT: '1rem',
        sm: '2rem',
        lg: '4rem',
        xl: '5rem',
        '2xl': '6rem',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

But as it was said, only works in x direction, that's padding-left and padding-right.
Is there a way to add vertical padding in the config file like horizontal one?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to accomplish what you want through the `container` object. But what I would do instead is set `container` to `false` in `corePlugins` and add it as a new component that I can fully customize at ease.

[docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-components)


[credits](https://dev.to/bourhaouta/tailwind-container-the-right-way-5g77)

Comment: @yamanidev thank you!!